# addEventListener to a link not working

Tags: javascript

I am trying to fire a event listener from a link. Why is below code not working?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

document.getElementById("test").addEventListener('click', function(event)){
alert('test');

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a  id ="test" class="button" href="#">Test</a><br>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi! Look in your browser's web console, it's telling you what's wrong. The solution is in the answers to the linked question. Basically: As of when you try to find the element, it doesn't exist yet, because your code is executed immediately when it's encountered. Unless you have a good reason for doing something else, put your scripts at the end of the `body`, just before the closing `</body>` tag.

Comment: The script is running before the DOM is created. When you select an element with `document.getElementById("test")`, it does not return any results. You can move your script tag to the bottom (before closing body), or surround your code with the `DOMContentLoaded` event.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
  <head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
     document.getElementById("test").addEventListener('click', function(event){
     alert('test');
     });
    });
   </script>
  </head>
  <body>
   <a id ="test" class="button" href="#">Test</a><br>
  </body>
 </html> --- try with given solution

Comment: Here you call addEventListener. you mmust have to intialize it inside the $(document).ready this is because as your control is not fully loaded before that you are going to use it so it gives you undefined error